# Should I remove or hide my annotations in MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I was wondering which would be faster/more efficient when it comes to taking off annotations from the map: hiding or removing. I need to remove and add 100 or so pins every time the user zooms in or out.

I can either loop through and hide all annotations using `setHidden:`, or just remove them using `removeAnnotations:`. I'm not sure which would be a better method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the standard method is to remove them. Less memory overhead. Not that 100 takes up that much, but still better to remove and re-add when needed then to hide.